# Update variable when value is present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple string of code. I want to show a default value when the page is loaded where the function `numResults()` is. At some point I want to update `numResults()` with a new value and then change the string without reloading the page.

```
$('#step1').before('Showing results 1 - ' + numResults());

function numResults(value) {
    var results = 10; // default number

    if (value) {
        return value; // show updated value
    } else {
        return results; // show default
    }
}
```

Comment: No ajax involved, is it? Please remove the tag.

Comment: you could do a typeof value !=='undefined' to check if the value is passed, If no value is passed display the default value. you can fetch the value to be passed however you want and  pass it to the function. IMO it would look better if the function itself loaded the value and then determined to show the value || the default value

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit as to what you are trying to do?  You say `if...value set`, but your function returns the value if it is set.

Comment: Yes, would be some kind of event listener. Could you please show us how and when the function is called "*at any point*"?

Comment: I updated my answer slightly. Maybe it makes more sense now? I want to dynamically change that string of text without reloading the page whenever the value changes.

Comment: Is this the only place where `numResults()` is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can utilize a [`jQuery.Callbacks` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) for this:

```
// flags: store latest value, and prevent same callback adding multiple times
var resultNumberChanged = $.Callbacks("memory unique");
resultNumberChanged.fire(10); // init with "default number"

resultNumberChanged.add(function(val) {
    $('#step1').before('Showing results 1 - ' + val); // update each time it changes
}); // will also be fired immediately, as there is the default value already

// then, at any point, e.g. inside the numResult function when there is a parameter
…
    resultNumberChanged.fire(newvalue);
```

Comment: I was able to implement this with some modifications to do what I needed. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This is a quintessential use case for knockout.js.

Running example at: http://jsfiddle.net/55fXu/1/

```
<div data-bind="text:numResults"/>

<script>
$(function() {
  function AppViewModel() {
    this.numResults = ko.observable(10);
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, close your if tag before start else.
Well, if you're trying to do something simple, try this:

```
$(function () {
        $("#myText").val(numResults());

        $("#myButton").click(function(){
            $("#myText").val(numResults("123"));
        });
    });

    function numResults(value) {
        var results = 10; // default number

        if (value) {
            return value; // show updated value
        }
        else {
            return results; // show default
        }
    }
```